# Redirect one ip to another within windows?

Tags: windows, networking

is it  possible to somehow tell windows that when I try to access ip a.b.c.d it should access w.x.y.z ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). On WindowsXP it is located at

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc
```

you will notice it has default routes setup already such as

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

you can then add your own route there

```
123.45.67.89    superduper
```

Comment: this is only a solution if you use a named connection. It does not work to redirect requests directly using IP address (a.b.c.d -> e.f.g.h)

Comment: It's disappointing that the question is asking about a.b.c.d -> w.x.y.z.  But the answer is a.b.c.d -> name.